# VBA Combining a double dimension variant in a single dimension variant

Tags: vba, loops, multidimensional-array

I am looping through a single dimension array, but the first value is a dobule dimension array:

```
Arr_UpdateCount(1) = Array(Arr_UpdateCount(ArrC_UpdateCount) - 1, SubObjectTotalCounter)
```

which results in the following according the locals:

```
Arr_UpdateCount(1)(1)=Arr_UpdateCount(ArrC_UpdateCount) - 1
Arr_UpdateCount(1)(2)=SubObjectTotalCounter
```

But what i would like it to do was to add the array values in each loop to the previous value:

```
Arr_UpdateCount(1) = _
Array(Arr_UpdateCount(1)(1)+Arr_UpdateCount(ArrC_UpdateCount) - 1, _
Arr_UpdateCount(1)(2)+ SubObjectTotalCounter)
```

However the above doesn't work.

Comment: Unless you have `Option Base 1` set (and that's a bad idea since you're working against the default array base), the first index of the array stored at `Arr_UpdateCount(1)` will be zero, not one.  Ditto for your main array.

Comment: Yes i am using `Option Base 1`. Whether i use Option base or not, will that have any impact on my issue?